# Como sobreescribir layouts y colors de una aplicación Android existente?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

Tengo que hacer unas personalizaciones a una aplicación ya existente que servirá como esqueleto para diferentes desarrollos. La idea es tocar lo mínimo posible los archivos ya existentes de la aplicación.
Con lo que me surge la siguiente duda, por ejemplo, con los **resources**.

Puedo "decirle" a la app de algún modo que coja los colores que yo defina en un fichero que se podrá llamar custom_colors.xml y si no encuentra ese color en ese fichero, vaya a buscarlo en el fichero por defecto colors.xml?

Dejo un ejemplo para que se entienda un poco mejor.

**custom_colors.xml**

```
 <color name="border">#000000</color>
 <color name="error">#FF0000</color>
 ...
```

**colors.xml**

```
  <color name="border">#FF0023</color>
  <color name="error">#FF2211</color>
  <color name="alert">#FFFF00</color>
  <color name="background">#CCCCCC</color>
  ...
```

El color **border** y **error** los tengo sobrescritos en mi fichero custom, pero alert y backgroung se tendrían que cojer del fichero colors.xml por defecto.

Gracias de antemano por vuestra ayuda!!

Comment: prueba con un <merge> i si no con un ternario <color name="border">@color/custom_colors_border ?@color/custom_colors_border: #FF0023</color>

Comment: Con un ternario no me sirve, tendría que modificar todos los ficheros de la app para hacer referencia a un fichero o a otro y no puedo. Necesito declarar en un solo sitio esta condición. Puedes montar un ejemplo de <merge>?

Answer (score 0):

Lo que quieres realizar solo es posible si en tu proyecto usas una biblioteca que define un colors.xml y su proyecto tiene su propio colors.xml

colors.xml de biblioteca:

```
 <color name="border">#000000</color>
 <color name="error">#FF0000</color>
 <color name="alert"></color>
 <color name="background"></color>
```

colors.xml de proyecto principal:

```
  <color name="border">#FF0023</color>
  <color name="error">#FF2211</color>
  <color name="alert">#FFFF00</color>
  <color name="background">#CCCCCC</color>
```

De esta forma los colores de `"alert"` y `"background"` se tomarían los colores definidos en `colors.xml` de proyecto principal.

Pero me parece una posible solución sería usando "Flavors" en este caso creas y configuras un directorio que contenga otros recursos incluyendo colors.xml y puedes cambiar a esta configuración mediante "Build Variants", revisa:

[Cómo configurar variantes de compilación](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants?hl=es)